# Avoiding wait time on queries

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor

I've noticed this pattern on my meteor app when calling a function, say recordInput:

```
wait on method : recordInput - 2647 ms
wait on method : recordInput - 1121 ms
wait on method : recordInput - 1714 ms
wait on method : recordInput - 820 ms
```

So it seems to me that the function, which is called asynchronously, is stacking up as it is called by multiple users.

I'm running the app on heroku, so if I wanted to reduce the wait time, would I increase the size of dyno or the number of dynos, or would neither of these changes make a difference due to the meteor / node architecture?

Comment: Where does that `wait on method : recordInput...` output come from?

Comment: That comes from kadira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor stacks up methods for a particular user, i'm not sure of your setup exactly but Meteor methods are set up in a particular order for a particular connection, the next method will not be called until the previous one is called and returns a result.

This of course means multiple connections can run synchronously, this only applies for the same connection.

If you want each to fire regardless of any previous methods waiting completion on the stack, begin your server side method with:

```
Meteor.methods({

    your_method_name: function() {

        this.unblock();

        ....

    }
});
```

[1] Meteor docs on `this.unblock()`: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock

Comment: Thank you. So this has arisen from the same user firing the function multiple times. If the queue relates to the same user is there anything to be gained by unblocking?

Comment: Yes if you use this.unblock the stack is ignored for that method, so you can get results faster, but it depends on your app because they can be returned out of the order they were called in